# Firebase Simple Login for Facebook fails with "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration"

Tags: angularjs, cordova, oauth, firebase, ionic-framework

I am following along with this article:
https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-07-25-ionic-simple-login.html

I am building an android app though.

When I click the facebook login button, Facebook gives me this error:

> Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

On Facebook Developers, in my app's basic settings, I have the site url and mobile site url set to `http://localhost/`. On the advanced screen, I have "Valid OAuth redirect URIs" set to include these urls:

`https://auth.firebase.com/v2/<firebase-app-name>/auth/facebook/callback`

`http://localhost`

`http://127.0.0.1`

`http://<firebase-app-name>.firebaseapp.com/`

`Client OAuth Login` and `Embedded browser OAuth Login` switches in the same section are set to "Yes".

In the `Status & Review` tab, I have made this app available to the general public.

I thought it might have something to do with the whitelisting of the URLs, but the article doesn't mention whitelisting android apps. I did edit my project root's config.xml file to include

```
<access origin="*.firebaseio.com" />
<access origin="auth.firebase.com" />
```

Strangely I don't see this in `<project-root>/platforms/android/res/xml/config.xml` after running `cordova build`. This is just a guess at this point, I have no clue what's going on and could use some help!

---

Note: `<firebase-app-name>` is set to the actual name of the firebase app, and my controller also includes the proper name.

---

Update: I have been playing around with the urls in `App Domains`, `Site URL`, and `Mobile Site URL` on the facebook developers page, figured that might be the other problem, but so far no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use Firebase authentication, you'll need to set the `Site URL` to `https://auth.firebase.com/v2/<firebase-app-name>/auth/facebook/callback`.

Comment: did all the above mentioned changes and changed the site url also and still I am getting the same error. Can anyone help me out here.

Answer (score 0):

@yatin, the problem yo have is you are including the .firebaseio.com extension of your app name.

For example

your appname = tester

your url = tester.firebaseio.com

https://auth.firebase.com/v2/tester.firebaseio.com/auth/facebook/callback -- WRONG

https://auth.firebase.com/v2/tester/auth/facebook/callback -- RIGHT

N.B. The app name without the .firebaseio.com